# selenium webdriver having issues targetting/clicking on a button | bootstrap

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I use a chrome web-based application. We use bootstrap, which makes it harder to simply right click an element in dev tools and get its xpath or cssselector.

Here is the code of a button I'm trying to click:

```
div class="pull-right"
button data-bind="click: $root.update, enable: !($root.isLoading() || $root.isRunning()) &amp;&amp; workOrderId() > 0, css: {'disabled' : ($root.isLoading() || $root.isRunning() || workOrderId() === 0) }" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm selectorgadget_selected" style="opacity: 0.6;">Calculate</button> == $0
```

IWebElement applyCalculate = driver.FindElement( By.CssSelector( ".btn-sm" ) );

```
IWebElement applyCalculate = driver.FindElement( By.CssSelector( ".btn-sm" ) );

try
{
      applyCalculate.Click();
      {
      };

}
catch (Exception)
{
      {
      };
}
```

I'm ok either using Classname, cssselector, xpath, pretty much anything that might work at this point. Any ideas? Element is found, but not clicking

Comment: So if you say that element is found and not clicking  - does it print any error? Are you sure that the element is found?

Comment: Please take a minute to fix the formatting and HTML in your question. Right now it's hard to read and not properly formatted.

Comment: Well if you have the code exactly as in example, it's possible that there is exception which is not printed because you have try catch

Answer (score 0):

**CODE**:

```
<div class="form-group form-group-sm" data-bind="visible: 
!$root.isCollapsed() &amp;&amp; !$root.isLocked()"> == $0
   ::before
 <div class="pull-right">
   <button data-bind="click: $root.update, enable:!
   ($root.isLoading() || $root.isRunning()) &amp;&amp; workOrderId() > 0, 
   css: {'disabled' : ($root.isLoading() || $root.isRunning() || 
   workOrderId() === 0) }" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" style=
   "opacity: 0.6;">Calculate</button>
 </div>
</div>
```

**SCRIPT**:

```
IWebElement applyCalculate = driver.FindElement(By.ClassName(".btn-sm"));

try
{
    if (applyCalculate != null)
    {
       applyCalculate.Click();
       applyCalculate.Click();
       {
       };
    }
    else
    {
        {
        };
    }
}
catch (Exception)
{
}
```